# Jquery UI dialog not close on Inner Application close

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery dialog box and under this dialog I put one division and under this division I load Iframe and in this Iframe I load one URL.

Now, when I press the URL window close button then the dialog box in still open.

So I want to do this, when I click on URL close then dialog will automatically close.

How this is achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is URL Close button is inside iframe? or that button is on dialog

Comment: Yes close button is there

Comment: close button is inside website, and website is load in iframe

Comment: @TanujVaja show your code or add a fiddle for what u tried.

Comment: @TanujVaja, Have try the answer. if that is what you want please accept the answer. so other people no need to waste there time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the parent window jQuery code within the page loaded inside the iframe like this

```
window.parent.jQuery('#dialogId').dialog('close');
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zv1L9fb2/)